# Known Folders y listado de música en UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, lista

Estoy desarrollando un reproductor de música, siendo mi primer aplicación UWP. Llegué a una instancia donde no sé cómo utilizar KnownFolders. Estuve viendo que con la siguiente sintaxis es posible:

```
var folder = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

¿Estoy en lo correcto?

¿Cómo puedo llevar esto hacia un listado (por ejemplo a un ListView)?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes recorrer los ficheros y añadirlos a una `ObservableCollection<MiModeloMp3Model>`, con esto ya podrás establecer la propiedad ItemsSource de tu ListView.

Sería algo así:

```
ObservableCollection<MiModeloMp3> mp3s = new ObservableCollection<MiModeloMp3>();
foreach (var file in files) 
{
    mp3s.add(new MiModeloMp3() { Name = ((StorageFile)file).Name });
}

myListView.ItemsSource = mp3s;
```

Recuerda que puedes acceder a varias propiedades de cada objeto "file" con la propiedad "Attributes".

Saludos.